# GeoNetwork : no search available currently: critical system checks remote index

Tags: geonetwork, debian, jetty, elasticsearch

I have GeoNetwork on Debian server (With Jetty). On the GeoNetwork home/main page, message saying "No search service available currently!". On the dashborad, it seems to have 3  non critical system errors. One regarding dashboard application. Another regards index is in readonly mode. Another regards metadata index errors. And one remote index critical system error. When i click on the remote index, there is the following message :

Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée

When i try to start elasticsearch as root, the message says :

```
_root@XXXXXXX:/opt/elasticsearch/bin# ./elasticsearch
\[2023-08-30T08:06:53,691\]\[ERROR\]\[o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler\] uncaught exception in thread \[main\]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:107) ~\[elasticsearch-7.17.8.jar:7.17.8\]__
```

An when i try to start as simple account :

```
\[2023-08-30T08:10:25,302\]\[ERROR\]\[o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  \]  exception during geoip databases update
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
main ERROR RollingFileManager (/opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch\_server.json) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch\_server.json (Permission non accordée) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch\_server.json (Permission non accordée)
2023-08-30 08:10:02,624 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory \[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@1f75a668\] unable to create manager for \[/opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch\_server.json\] with data \[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@35399441\[pattern=/opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.json.gz, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=\[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=134217728)\]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, useMax=false), advertiseURI=null, layout=ESJsonLayout{patternLayout={"type": "server", "timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZZ}", "level": "%p", "component": "%c{1.}", "cluster.name": "${sys:es.logs.cluster\_name}", "node.name": "%node\_name", "message": "%notEmpty{%enc{%marker}{JSON} }%enc{%.-10000m}{JSON}"%notEmpty{, %node\_and\_cluster\_id }%notEmpty{, "trace.id": "%trace\_id" }%exceptionAsJson }
2023-08-30 08:10:02,626 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
2023-08-30 08:10:02,687 main ERROR RollingFileManager (/opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log (Permission non accordée) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log (Permission non accordée)
2023-08-30 08:10:02,706 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2023-08-30 08:10:02,707 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2023-08-30 08:10:02,707 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling" for logger config "root"
2023-08-30 08:10:02,707 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling\_old" for logger config "root"\_
```

Comment: I have just edited my initial post. In adding new errors messages when i try to start elasticsearch as root and with a basic account/user.

Answer (score 0):

The errors in GeoNetwork you are seeing are caused by GN not being able to connect to Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch is the backend server GeoNetwork uses for searching. Check that the Elasticsearch connection parameters in GeoNetwork are right. Connection details are in `WEB-INF/config.properties` GeoNetwork file.

```
es.protocol=http
es.port=9200
es.host=localhost
es.url=${es.protocol}://${es.host}:${es.port}
es.username=
es.password=
```

You can find more information in the [GeoNetwork documentation](https://docs.geonetwork-opensource.org/stable/install-guide/installing-index/).